# php-updating a file and reading concurrently

Tags: php, file

I want to regularly update (rewrite, not append) a txt file from php by using `file_put_contents`. another php API reads this file and prints the content for the user.

is it possible that when the user wants to read the file via PHP API, it returns empty? because when the first PHP file tries to update the file, it erases the data and then writes new content. if it is possible, how to avoid it?

Comment: It is certainly possible that might happen, depending on how your server handles file locking. I'd do it as a three-step operation - output the file to a new name, when complete, erase the original file and then rename your new one to the old name. Have the "other" API check to see if the file exists and if it does not, it's in the short window between erase and rename, and it can re-try. Depends on how long it takes to output the file, and how regularly you want to update it as to how much of a problem this might be.

Comment: This sounds like a use case for a database, not a file

Comment: Also, where is the content coming from? If it's coming from a database, why add in a file at all?

Answer (score 1):

It can prevent and sure the source file won't be empty try following solution :

- you can keep your processing text file in tmp folder e.g. tmp_txt which you can create parallel to same location where as your current text file, so first your text file goes to in this tmp folder
- Create a shell script file and keep that under the tmp folder or any other folder
- add the shell script which will observer the file size, and put that in to cron job scheduler

> find /your project root path/tmp_txt/ -type f -size +1 -name "mytext.txt" -exec mv {} /your project root paht/folder where you want it/

- "find" is command for search the file and next your tmp folder path"
- "-type f" this will consider only the file
- "-size +1" +1 mean above 1 KB
- "-name "mytext.txt"" you can define your file name, if dynamic names then -name "*.txt"
- "-exec mv {}" this will move the file on path that next to it, if match the file size with above condition which is 1KB you can change that as per your need
- e.g. cronjob entry which will run the every minutes

> - - - - - bash /yor project root path/tmp_txt/shellscriptfilename>> /dev/null 2>&1